# What is a word meaning "has always been happening" up to the current point time?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have an active event that may or may not have declared beginning or ending dates. When there is no ending date set, I'm using "ongoing" to indicate that this event will continue for the foreseeable future. What is a corresponding term for when there is no defined beginning date and the event "has always been" active?

Comment: Maybe "for all time"?  Technically, all things have a set start date (the birth of the universe), so I don't know if that's exactly what you mean here.

Comment: To me *ongoing* refers to a present activity and says nothing about its prospects for the future.

Comment: @Nick2253 Tt's been in effect long enough that the actual start date is irrelevant. In reality it's years, but I'm looking for something not in terms of measured time like that.

Comment: @CarSmack It's presently active and will stay that way until someone sets a future date for it to end (if ever).

Comment: It is not so much a "term" than a "phrase". "What is the corresponding **phrase**?"

Answer (score 3):

Which has been running since ***time immemorial***...?

Comment: I was thinking the same.  Another phrase, "since time out of mind" is an old-fashioned expression used in the southern US states.

Comment: @Theresa The Southern states don't need to worry about the use of space.

Comment: Right idea but a bit grand for the context. Per my comments above the reality is on the order of years, but I'm looking for something not necessarily in terms of time.

Comment: It's interesting that all the terms of this kind of thing sound antique or folksy or old-fashioned. (I think "time immemorial" has a specific legal meaning in some jurisdictions, but in general use is fine.)